# Show or Hide buttons from property value

Tags: aurelia

I have a list of items in a table and want to enable or disable some buttons based off a boolean property called "enabled". Code for the buttons are as follows

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" show.bind="item.enabled"  click.delegate="toggleEnabled()">Disable</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" show.bind="!item.enabled" click.delegate="toggleEnabled()">Enable</button>
```

No matter what the value for item.enabled, only the disable button shows. Wondering what I am missing?

Comment: are there any errors thrown? what does your view model look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `item.enabled` is being returned as a `boolean` and not a `string`.

Comment: hand meets forehead moment

Comment: Yeah, that'll do it too!

Answer (score 5):

`click.delegate="item.toggleEnabled()"` add the `item.` before toggleEnabled and you'll be good to go!

Here is an example with working code: https://github.com/AshleyGrant/skeleton-navigation/tree/so-answer-20150416-02/src